"Shortest program that fits training data is the best possible generalisation" what is this theorem?
In a class of MIT, an orator says that the "Shortest program that fits training data is the best possible generalisation" and that's it's not just philosophy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) but actually a mathematical fact backed by a formal (simple) proof.
What is the name of that mathematical theorem? Is this the "Minimum description length"? That's what ChatGPT told me when I asked it the question but it doesn't look like a proved mathematical theorem to me but rather something similar albeit slightly more formalised that the Occam's razor.

Occam's razor is an advice to make as few unproven statements for a hypothesis as possible. It is not a rigorous mathematical concept. It is used in science and helps to understand the world better. And forget ChatGTP , a tool more confusing than helpful in any sense.

The ‘proof’ is simple. Let’s say you label all of the programs somehow (say by the binary representation). Then program $i$ has prior probability $p_i$ and we have $\sum_i p_i=1$. Any converging series must also converge to $0$, so $\lim_i p_i=0$. Alternatively, you could say that the average probability of the first $n$ theories is at most $1/n$, so again in the limit, the average complexity of the first $n$ programs approaches $0$. The more complicated your program is, the less likely it is, simply because there are more programs with high length/complexity than small programs.
Note however, that this doesn’t mean that individual complex programs are less likely than individual simple programs, just that this is true in aggregate.
There’s lots of places that this comes up. The most direct is Kolmogorov complexity, but it also shows up in underfitting/overfitting in Machine Learning.

If I'm not mistaken, there are more programs with high length/complexity, so although their individual likelihood is indeed lower, aggregated together the likelihood of a complex program being might not?

Sure, constant functions are the simplest programs but they’re unlikely to solve most problems.
